# Find a range (7 cells) in a range (80 rows, 7 columns)

Tags: excel, vba, range

I would like to increment a counter (variable x) each time I found 7 greys cells (on one line) in myRange: 80rows x 7columns
I don't really know where to start, then any ideas are welcome.

```
Dim rCell  As Range
For Each rCell In myRange
    ' Looking for grey cells, the whole line of 7 days
    If rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200) Then

        ' something like that
        'If the 7 cells in a row are grey then x = x + 1

    End If
Next rCell
```

If you can point me in the right direction, it will be great.
Is it possible to replace rCell by a range of 7 cells?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim rCell  As Range, rw as range, n as long

For Each rw in myRange.Rows   'loop over rows
    For Each rCell In rw      'loop cells in row  

        If rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200) Then n = n + 1
        If n = 7 Then 
            x = x + 1
            n = 0  'reset counter
        End If 

    Next rCell
Next rw
```